# Why Duracell Security MN21 12 V 23A Alkaline Battery cannot provide 12v to Computer Fan 12 V 0.16A

Tags: voltage, amperage, fan

Fan spinning only at 5V (~600 RPM). Why this happened? The fan should spin at full speed.

Comment: You're using a small 12 V battery. Your car also has a 12V battery. Do you think you could also use this small MN21 12V battery to **start your car**? Or do you think that might not work? Hint: learn about **internal resistance** of a battery. That small MN21 battery simply cannot deliver 0.16A at 12 V.

Comment: It's abundantly clear what op is asking...

Comment: The "23A" in this case is a size code, not a measure of current that the battery can supply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duracell MN21 battery : [(datasheet available here](http://uk.farnell.com/duracell/mn21/battery-mn21-33mah-12v-pk2/dp/1892795?ost=MN21%20battery&iscrfnonsku=false&ddkey=http%3Aen-GB%2FElement14_United_Kingdom%2Fsearch)) : "typical impedance : 22 ohms".

Voltage lost in battery at fan's rated current (0.16A) : 22 * 0.16 = 3.52V.

Voltage available to fan : 8.48V assuming fan actually takes 0.16A.

It's worse than this because the fan will take a higher current (its stall current) while starting, therefore dropping a higher voltage across the battery's internal resistance. If it takes 0.3A, there will be only about 5V left across the fan, which is about what you're seeing.

That battery is designed for things like remote key locks, not for enough power to move air around. You need a more serious battery.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation. Can you advise this type of battery?